# New to linux and need help

Tags: system-requirements

i am trying to install Ubuntu in an old laptop which is an Dual-core processor and has only 1024 MB ram. I have seen that the system requirement says 2Gb ram but i only have 1Gb. My question is will i be able to install Ubuntu?

Comment: It's not a good idea. Try [Xubuntu 18.04](https://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu 18.04](https://lubuntu.net/), which handle low RAM much better, which are official Ubuntu variants, and which you can also get help with here.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not recommended by Ubuntu, so it is not a good idea to try it on a PC that has not the minimum requirements.
It would be better if you try [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) since it is possible to run them on PCs with low performances.